# mvc c# file upload as byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, upload, byte

I have to upload files and other data in a single submit of UploadFile.cshtml form

I have a base class which is the input of mvc action in home controller.

My base class, mvc action method and cshtml part with Razor script is given below

I have to get the file as byte array in the mvc action while submitting the UploadFile.cshtml form

**My Base class**

```
public class FileUpload
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
  public byte[] Photo {get;set;}
}
```

**MyMVCAction**

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadFile(FileUploadobj)
{
  FileUploaddata=obj;
}
```

**Mycshtmlform**

```
@modelMVC.Models.FileUpload
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadFile","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{

<fieldset>
<legend>File Upload</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Age)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Age)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.Label("UploadPhoto");
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo"/>
</div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</p>

</fieldset>

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think better achieve it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(FileUpload obj) 
{
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
    {
       obj.Photo = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
    }  

    //return some action result e.g. return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I hope it helps.